# Decay of a $J/\psi$ Meson to $e^+$ & $e^-$

Tags: homework-and-exercises

i just began studying Feynman diagrams, and for this week I’ve got a few exercises to do about this topic.

One of them really confuses me, as I can‘t understand how and why it happens, and which is correct now - The Decay of a J/psi Meson.

Our Task is to draw the Feynman diagram of this particle decaying into a electron/positron pair. I read that the strong force is what holds the charm/anticharm together and so I thought that the decay could happen via a gluon.
After that I read on a different site, that the J/psi Meson decays in a l+/l- (lepton) pair via a photon. Which is now the correct way and why?
I understand there are probabilities for lots of different decays, but why is the photon one the correct now, or a both a possibility, and how does the correct one look like in the end?

Thank you for your help[image]

Comment: There is no gluon $e^+ e^-$ vertex. Leptons do not "feel" the strong interaction.

Comment: Why is it that way? Why is there no gluon e+ e- vertex?

Comment: Because nature is built like that. Leptons do not carry "colour charge".

Comment: So the left diagram is the right one?

Comment: The left one is a possible diagram. The c quark has electromagnetic charge $2/3$ and the electron electromagnetic charge $-1$ (opposite charges for the corresponding antiparticles). Thus both "feel"ythe  electromagnetic interaction through their couplings (vertices) to the photon field.